# Exit in For loop - Windows Command Processor (CMD.EXE)

Tags: command-line, for-loop, cmd, control-flow

I am trying to find way to break / exit from FOR loop, if there are any error occured.
Below is content of batch file.

```
@echo on

set myfile=D:\sample.txt

FOR /F "tokens=1,2 delims=," %%i in (%myfile%) do call :process "%%i"

:process
set recfile=%1%

echo %recfile%
echo "Step in Test1"
echo %errorlevel%
pause;

exit /B 0
If %errorlevel% NEQ 0 goto :fail1

:fail1
echo "Step in fail1"
pause;
exit /B 9993

:EOF
```

Sample.txt has multiple records. If there are any error occured then I am expecting to exit the batch file rather then checking the complete sample.txt file. e.g. on statement
echo %recfile%, If I place some wrong command ech %recfile% which is incorrect command then I am expecting that it should go to fail1 level and exit. It's catured the error code successfully and going to fail1 level however after this statment, it's checking the sample.txt file (next record) again. Is there any way, If I can break / exit FOR loop.

Please advice.

Thanks,

Answer (score 7):

Joey's answer is great.  I have used it with success.  I discovered that you don't have to exit the script though.  You can use `goto :SomeLabel`, where `:SomeLabel` is a label outside of the loop.

```
FOR /F "tokens=1,2 delims=," %%i in (%myfile%) do (
  if defined exit goto :ParseError
  call :process "%%i"
)

@echo SUCCESS: %myfile%
goto :RestOfScript

:ParseError
@echo FAILURE: cannot parse %myfile%
@echo Using defaults...

:RestOfScript
...
```

Answer (score 5):

You can set a variable, meaning that the complete loop should be aborted and use it like this:

```
:fail1
echo "Step in fail1"
pause
set exit=1
```

And you'd change the loop like this:

```
FOR /F "tokens=1,2 delims=," %%i in (%myfile%) do (
  if defined exit (
    exit /b 9993
  ) else (
    call :process "%%i"
  )
)
```

(broken into multiple lines for readability).

Since you are just calling a subroutine from the `for` loop there is no way for this subroutine to exit the loop directly. Hence the workaround with a variable.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to call a label

```
set USBDRIVE=SETLOCAL 
set exit=ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

FOR %%D IN (C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z) DO (
  DIR %%D:\SOURCES\INSTALL.WIM > nul 2>&1 && call set USBDRIVE=%%D: && call set exit=1
  if defined exit goto :dd3
)
:dd3
```

Comment: What is `ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` doing here?!