# DOS script to remove identical files by content

Tags: scripting, dos, batch-file, windows-scripting

I have a directory with several thousand text files that I need to process. Some of these files are identical while others are identical except the timestamp varies by a few seconds / milliseconds. I need some way to automate the deletion of identical files and only keep one copy.

I'm thinking of something like:

```
while there are files in the directory still
{
    get file                    // e.g., file0001

    while (file == file + 1)    // e.g., file0001 == file0002 using 'fc' command
    {
        delete file + 1
    }

    move file to another directory
}
```

Is something like this even possible in Microsoft Windows Server 2003's DOS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Of course it is. Everything is possible in batch. :D

This batch doesn't actually delete files. It just echos the result of the comparison. You can delete either one of the files if you find two that are the same.

Save the code as `CleanDuplicates.bat` and start the program with `CleanDuplicates {Folder}`

Provided AS IS, without any guarantees! I don't want you knocking on my door because your entire server is messed up. ;-)

The code actually calls itself recursively. This could maybe be done in a different way but hey, it works. It also starts itself again in a new cmd, because that makes cleaning up easier. I tested the script in Windows Vista Business, but it should work on Server 2003 as well. Hey, it even has a help function. ;-)
It contains two loops that each return every file, so when you implement the actual deleting, it may report that some files don't exist, because they are deleted in an earlier iteration.

```
@echo off
rem Check input. //, /// and //// are special parameters. No parameter -> help.
if %1check==//check goto innerloop
if %1check==///check goto compare
if %1check==////check goto shell
if %1check==/hcheck goto help
if %1check==check goto help

rem Start ourselves within a new cmd shell. This will automatically return to
rem the original directory, and clear our helper environment vars.
cmd /c %0 //// %1
echo Exiting
goto end

:shell
rem Save the current folder, jump to target folder and set some helper vars
set FCOrgFolder=%CD%
cd %2
set FCStartPath=%0
if not exist %FCStartPath% set FCStartPath=%FCOrgFolder%\%0

rem Outer loop. Get each file and call ourselves with the first special parameter.
for %%a in (*.*) do call %FCStartPath% // "%2" "%%a"

goto end

:innerloop
rem Get each file again and call ourselves again with the second special parameter.
for %%b in (*.*) do call %FCStartPath% /// %2 %3 "%%b"
goto end

:compare
rem Actual compare and some verbose.
if %3==%4 goto end
echo Comparing
echo * %3
echo * %4

fc %3 %4 >nul

rem Get results
if errorlevel 2 goto notexists
if errorlevel 1 goto different

echo Files are identical
goto end

:different
echo Files differ
goto end

:notexists
echo File does not exist
goto end

:help

echo Compares files within a directory.
echo Usage: %0 {directory}
goto end

:end
```

Comment: Is the answer not ok? If not, what's wrong? Can I improve it?

Comment: It does the trick! I'm right now modifying it to delete the duplicate identical files. Is it possible for you to modify it so that when the script finds two files that differ, that it just moves onto the next file? And instead of looping back to the beginning of the file list, just compare it with the next sequential file? Right now it's comparing against ALL files - O(n^2) - but I know that if two files differ, no subsequent files will be the same.

Comment: Yes, a good solution can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184408/exit-in-for-loop-windows-command-processor-cmd-exe

Comment: It shows how to set a variable and detect inside a loop if that variable is set and how to exit the loop. It also shows how to use parentheses to group a list of command in the loop. This allows you to check the variable on each iteration and call the other file too.

Comment: That answer also seems to illustrate the possibility to use call to jump to a subroutine. That would eliminate the need for the recursive call using the dummy first parameter, although it will work just fine as it is now.