# How to stop the limit the search of a DIR /S after it found something

Tags: batch-file, cmd, windows-scripting

I'm trying to look for a file in a drive in BATCH and so I used the following command:

```
DIR c:\directory\* /s/b | FIND "filename.txt"
```

the problem is once I find the file, it still searches… So I was wondering if there was a parameter or something that would stop the search after it found at least 1 result.

**edit**

I was trying something like

```
FOR %%G IN (DIR c:\directory\* /s/b | FIND "filename.txt") DO copy %%G
```

then I would add another command line to exit the loop once the copy command is done.

Comment: I was trying something like

`FOR %%G IN (DIR c:\directory\* /s/b | FIND "filename.txt") DO copy %%G`                                                                                               then I would add another command line to exit the loop once the copy command is done.

Comment: I have added your comment to the text in the question.

Comment: `dir` already has the ability to search, no need to pipe the output to `find`

Answer (score 1):

There was a similar question here: [Exit in For loop - Windows Command Processor (CMD.EXE)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184408/exit-in-for-loop-windows-command-processor-cmd-exe)

And instead of: `DIR c:\directory\* /s/b | FIND "filename.txt"`

you can use this: `DIR /s /b c:\directory\filename.txt`

The result is not as I would expect... :-) Try it!
(You could also use wildcards for "filename.txt")

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you can do is :

```
DIR c:\directory* /s/b | FIND "filename.txt" | more
```

This way you need to press enter if more than a page of results are found. But this won't stop the `dir /s`, because you cannot tell it when to stop.

**edit:** Regarding your comment how to stop a for loop, see below.

Instead of the `dir | find`, I use [Locate32](http://www.locate32.net/) in this example. Take a look at it, it is similar to the suggestion of [schnaader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7001060/how-to-stop-the-limit-the-search-of-a-dir-s-after-it-found-something/7001203#7001203) to store a list of all files in a text file. Locate32 creates a database, and is able to update it automatically based on a schedule. You can quickly search in the database.

The next example searches for `cmd.exe` somewhere below c:\windows. It searches for the whole filename, so it does not find `appcmd.exe`. because of the `goto :skip`, it stops after the first result is displayed.

```
@echo off

FOR /f %%G IN ('"C:\Program Files\Locate\Locate.exe" -p c:\windows -lw cmd.exe') do (
  echo %%G
  goto :skip
)

:skip
echo done
```

Comment: I've been thinking about using the FOR to do the exact same thing, that might solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There might be some clever trick like sending Ctrl+C to DIR after getting a result or Windows Powershell could help, but I doubt it. Also, I don't know any parameters to control number of results for it and I don't think there are any.

If you want to do something like this, use your favorite programming language and do it there. Batch scripts are powerful, but some things just are too complex or thinking about solutions just wastes too much time.

By the way, if you do such `FIND` operations often, I'd suggest something like this:

```
 REM Script to build a filename index for all your drives

 DIR C:\* /s /b > index.txt
 DIR D:\* /s /b >> index.txt
 REM ...more drives here

 REM And you might want to compress index.txt afterwards
```

After that, you can just `FIND` files in the index which is *much* faster although you might have to recreate the index every now and then.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot limit the loop by seconds but how many times you want to loop it. Im not sure if the following example relates to your specific problem but i like to scare my friends with fake viruses. I found that you can pause it while making a command in notepad. Ex: (@echo OFF echo you are being hacked dir/s pause. This pauses the one dir/s so it is not in a loop so it is singular, this will also make it go on for one second (how long the dir/s singular is.) You can extend it by typing it more. Ex: (@echo OFF echo you are being hacked dir/s dir/s dir/s dir/s pause (this will make it go on for at least 5 seconds before it stops. I hope this helps and is understandable.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know to do this without searching the entire device before setting the variable is to use PowerShell. This might not have been as obvious in 2011 when the question was asked.

The cmd FOR loop will complete the command before it does the DO block. PowerShell pipes push the data through as it is found.

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /F "delims=" %%f IN (' ^
    powershell -NoProfile -Command ^
        "Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\' -Recurse -Filter '*testfile.jar' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |" ^
        "Select-Object -First 1 |" ^
        "ForEach-Object { $_.FullName }" ^
    ') DO (
    SET "FN=%%~f"
)

ECHO "%FN%"
```