# How can i insert the password from a text file using cmd?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command, command-prompt, rar

I am trying to open a password protected Rar file with cmd and when it asks for a password I want it to 
automatically insert the password stored in a text file.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose WinRAR has CLI for that stuff:

```
unrar x -p your_password your_rar_file.rar
```

Instead of `your_password` you can read from the file:

```
unrar x -p 'cat /path/to/passwdfile' your_rar_file.rar
```

Comment: Thank you @ZavenZareyan. I am using this in a for loop, is there a way to stop or break out of the loop when the password is correct?

Comment: You should go in this direction: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591758/batch-script-loop

Comment: Thank you @ZavenZareyan. `for /F "tokens=*" %A in (myfile.txt) do UnRar x file.rar -p%A ` i am using this command and it works but the only problem is that even when it finds the correct password it continues to try other password and i want it to stop or break out of the loop when it finds the correct password, is there a simple way to do that?

Comment: Set variable, check it in every loop, stop if it is true. Similar example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184408/exit-in-for-loop-windows-command-processor-cmd-exe